# javascript GET into html

Tags: javascript, html, get

I'm trying to do a GET using javascript and show the result in html. Here's my code

```
    <script>
    var x;
    $.get( "http://ip", function( data ) {
    x = data;
    });
    document.write(x);
    </script>
```

Now, ip is an ip of mine which is serving some array, something with the structure `[["","",""],["","",""],["","",""]]`.

This doesn't work, because when I open the html file on my browser, I see only the following line:

```
[object Object]
```

What's the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

[jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) is asynchronous, and the data returned is an array, so you can use `JSON.stringify` to convert it to a readable string

```
$.get('http://ip', function(data) {
    document.write(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

Comment: technically correct, but now you're doing `document.write` after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: ...and it doesn't address OP's `[object Object]` problem either.

Comment: Your fix still won't work. See @BlueSkies comment. You'll have to use another method, `$(selector).html(data)` or something.

Comment: Sure it will work. If he just wants to test the `$.get`, `document.write` is a pretty straightforward way to do it - http://jsbin.com/ikIlIGA/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Hm actually, it doesn't work. Now nothing at all gets printed.

Answer (score 0):

Your url in wrong. Try using `encodeURI()` around your url...and `x` is undefined, because at the time you call `docment.write(x)` `x`'s value has not been set yet by your `$.get()` method's `function` argument.